# calculating object placement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to place an object in the middle height wise of an area of the screen. I thought this code would work to calculate the Y position of my object:

```
var y = $chart.offset().top + $chart.outerHeight()/2;
```

But the object is displaying about 60% from the top of the chart, lower then I want it. Here are some actual numbers from the debugger:

```
$chart.offset().top
367.79999923706055
$chart.outerHeight()
451
y
593.2999992370605
```

What would be the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Do you have to position it programmaticaly? What about CSS? Because it would be utterly easy to do it with CSS...

Comment: The object I am creating gets generated as the result of a mouse over event. Not sure how I would set the position I want with CSS.

Comment: As long as you'd set your generated object correct CSS class name it would automatically get styles as per your static stylesheet.

Comment: Can you tell me what CSS I wouud use to get the object to diplay where I want?

Comment: Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CSH9/)

Comment: Ah so simple. I just added top: '50%' instead of setting top to an absolute position. Thank you so much. I'd vote this as the best answer, but it's a comment, not an answer so I can't.

Comment: I've written an answer that can be voted-up and/or accepted if this is the approach you took in the end.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did and it works. I have up voted and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems you're not strictly bound to use jQuery for this solution (comments), but you didn't know about any other alternative. So I propose one.

### Alternative approach - use CSS

Instead of using Javascript to position your element, you can use CSS instead and position your element `fixed` in the middle of the screen. A couple of most obvious benefits:

1. You don't have to execute additional code on the client = increased performance
2. Element stays centralised regardless of document scrolling - if you'd want the same using Javascript you should recalculate position on scroll event but element would still be *jumping* when document would be fast scrolled as Javascript execution is not *that instant (yet)*

Since you're adding your element dynamically, all you have to do is set it particular CSS class name which defines central position in your CSS file.

If you don't know how to position an element in the middle of the screen, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CSH9/) shows you how. It just positions element in the middle of the viewport but doesn't generate new elements as it seems you already know how to do that.

#### Required CSS

```
.centralise {
  width: 200px; /* set dimension */
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%; /* move top left to screen centre */
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -100px; /* offset by half element's size left and up */
  text-align: center; /* centralise text within element */
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

If you'll be putting your element 50% top and left, you have to give it a particular dimension, so you can set exact negative margins to put it dead centre.

### No fixed dimensions possible?

If you can't set specific element dimension, then `margin: 25% auto;` should help with that. But in this case it will only be positioned horizontally in the dead centre. Vertical position is usually not that problematic, as you can put elements in the top half or approximately centre and it will still look like centralised. Sometimes it may even be better to have it higher than centre, depending on your document content.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set `y` as `(height of window / 2) - (height of element / 2)`.

```
var y = $(window).height() /2 - $chart.outerHeight()/2;
```

Also, check the CSS:

```
position:absolute;
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CY38d/)

Comment: That does not do it at all. Your code came up with 4 for Y. I thought perhaps you did not mean to divide $(window).height() by 2, but that was not right either - that came up with 233.

Comment: How are you setting the `y` value? Are you having `position:absolute;`?

Comment: This is part of a django based app with a lot of templates, javascript, and jQuery. It would be very hard to extract a piece to post. Yes, position:absolute is being used. The CSS has `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0`

Comment: How are you setting the `y` value for `$chart`? Also, what object is `$chart`? You can see the Live Demo, the solution works. So, the problem should be with the CSS. Check in JS Console for `padding` or `margin`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'How are you setting the y value for $chart?' In the item I am creating I am simply doing `$popup_canvas.css({top: y + "px", left: x + "px"});` $chart is a jqplot chart: `[
<div id=​"chart_0" style=​"width:​ 95%;​ height:​ 450px;​ position:​ relative;​ " class=​"jqplot-target">​…​</div>​' The item I am adding has `margin: 0; padding: 0`

Comment: Is the element a `div`? Coz the `div` I see has `position:relative;`.

Comment: $chart is position relative, but $popup is position: absolute: `[
<canvas class=​"fails" style=​"pointer-events:​ none;​ visibility:​ hidden;​ position:​ absolute;​ cursor:​ pointer;​ ">​
, 
<div class=​"fails" style=​"background-color:​ transparent;​ width:​ 10em;​ visibility:​ hidden;​ position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 0px;​ left:​ 0px;​ background-position:​ initial initial;​ background-repeat:​ initial initial;​ ">​…​</div>​
]`

Answer (score 0):

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktraff/yaark/).

If you're looking for simply the center of your parent element, you could just use `height()` and append your element within the parent container:

```
var $parent = $('#parent');
var middle = $parent.height() / 2;
var $child = $(document.createElement('div'));
$child.attr("id", "child").text("hi")
   .css("position", "absolute")
   .css("top", middle - $child.height() / 2);
$parent.append($child);
```

Comment: This is not placing it correctly for me. To experiment, I used hard coded numbers for Y until I found what it should be for my test case - 555 placed it right in the middle of my chart area. Here's what your code generated for me:
  
`$parent.height()/2`
`225.5`
`$child.height()/2`
`53`
`top`
`172`

Comment: You could also try `outerHeight()`, as this accounts for padding and border

Comment: height() and outerHeight() are both the same - 451

Comment: Any chance you could create a jsfiddle to see?  Which elements are you calculating outerheight() for?  The parent as well as the chart, or just one?

Comment: It would be very hard to extract it from the app and make it into a jsfiddle. I am calling outerHeight() on the chart. There are multiple charts on the page, and I want the new item to be centered on the chart they are currently in. When I do this `$chart.offset().top + $chart.outerHeight()/2 - $popup_items.height()` it's very close - 578 - but I would think I should be able to calculate the exact center point.